# What is the purpose of a dot before an additional CSS property?

Tags: css, cross-browser, stylesheet

This is what I have in the code:

```
min-height: 35px;
.min-height: 25px;
}
```

What does the second line do? I assume it serves cross browser styling purposes but not sure which one for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be it is targetting IE 6 and 7, though usually `_` or `-` were used instead.

> Due to a parsing error, Internet Explorer 6 and below wouldn't fail on
>   properties that were prefixed with non-alphanumeric characters.

and

> Although Internet Explorer 7 corrected its behavior when a property
>   name is prefixed with an underscore or a hyphen, other
>   non-alphanumeric character prefixes are treated as they were in IE6.
>   Therefore, if you add a non-alphanumeric character such as an asterisk
>   (*) immediately before a property name, the property will be applied
>   in IE and not in other browsers.

http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#unrecommended-vendor_prefix